# Receiveing data from Arduino using Java

Tags: java, arduino

I found a Genius game project with Arduino, so I tried to implement and expand a little. I did a GUI using Java to start the game on Arduino (send data), and I want to show how many sequences the player completed. To do this, I need to receive data from Arduino, but I don't know how to do it and I can't find good examples.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A while back I wrote a Java program to receive bio metric readings from an Arduino.

The Arduino would just loop, writing the data to Serial.print(). 
My java program would listen on serial port COM1, and read the incoming data byte at a time. I used the [Java Simple Serial Connector(JSSC)](https://code.google.com/archive/p/java-simple-serial-connector/) library to read the data. I don't think its been touched in two years, but everything worked fine for me and it was fairly simple to set up.

Also,check out the wiki for some simple examples.
Hope it helps!